# Retrieve data in group based on the Value of other column

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

I have one table with the following Column.

```
BoxNumber          Status
580                 4 
581                 4
582                 4
583                 4
584                 2
585                 2
586                 4
587                 4
588                 4
589                 4
590                 2
591                 2
```

I need one select Query to get the following output .

```
StartingBoxNumber EndingBoxNumber    Status
580                     583           4
584                     585           2
586                     589           4
590                     591           2
```

Comment: Please make it more clear. Also, format the table source data to be aligned well. Your question is hard to read. What should "status" field contain in the resulting recordset?

Comment: I have reformatted the data to make it readable.  I can see what is needed, I think, though haven't solved it in SQL: start with the lowest BoxNumber (580), which has status 4.  Now step through the box numbers in ascending order until you reach one whose status is NOT 4 (584).  You now have your first result: 580 to the box number immediately preceding 584 (583) have status 4.

Comment: The solution probably involves the LEAD() and LAG() analytic functions.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the result with a single scan of the table, using analytics to define "groups" of contiguous rows:

```
SQL> SELECT MIN(boxnumber), MAX(boxnumber), status
  2    FROM (SELECT boxnumber, status,
  3                 SUM(status_change) over(ORDER BY boxnumber) group_id
  4             FROM (SELECT boxnumber, status,
  5                           CASE
  6                              WHEN lag(status) over(ORDER BY boxnumber)
  7                                   = status
  8                               AND lag(boxnumber) over(ORDER BY boxnumber)
  9                                   = boxnumber - 1 THEN
 10                               0
 11                              ELSE
 12                               1
 13                           END status_change
 14                      FROM box))
 15   GROUP BY status, group_id
 16   ORDER BY 1;

MIN(BOXNUMBER) MAX(BOXNUMBER)     STATUS
-------------- -------------- ----------
           580            583          4
           584            585          2
           586            589          4
           590            591          2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming box numbers are always consecutive:

```
SELECT  COALESCE(
        LAG(Boxnumber) OVER (ORDER BY BoxNumber),
        (
        SELECT  MIN(BoxNumber)
        FROM    mytable
        )) AS StartBoxNumber,
        BoxNumber AS EndBoxNumber,
        status
FROM    mytable qo
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
        SELECT  NULL
        FROM    mytable  qi
        WHERE   qi.boxnumber = qo.boxnumber + 1
                AND qi.status = qo.status
        )
```